# $\min(\det(\mathbf{A}))$ for special matrix $\mathbf{A}$

Tags: determinant, maxima-minima, symmetric-matrices, positive-definite

(The construction of matrix $\mathbf{A}$ is not difficult to be understood. You can first jump to **A Toy Example** to take a glance. Any idea or suggestion would be appealing for me.)

---

**Update #2:**

The original problem has been resolved in [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/430401/min-det-mathbfa-for-special-matrix-mathbfa).

---

**Update #1:**

I get a partial answer and a hint from @Noam D. Elkies in [mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/430401/min-det-mathbfa-for-special-matrix-mathbfa). I may understand his/her partial answer for $(\text{Q}2)$. Are the ideas given by @Noam D. Elkies correct? What should I do to complete the proof? Could you please provide more details about that? Or do you have some other ideas?

---

**The Original Problem:**

Given $N,D\in\mathbb{Z}^+~(D\ge N)$ and $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}^+$, the vector $\mathbf{p}$ and the matrix $\mathbf{A}_\mathbf{p}$ are defined as follows:

- $\mathbf{p}=[p_1,p_2,\cdots,p_N]$, where $p_i$s are selected from $\{1,2,\cdots,D\}$ and satisfying the condition of $(p_1<p_2<\cdots<p_N)$.
- Given $\mathbf{p}$, there is $\mathbf{A}_\mathbf{p}=[a_{ij}]_{N\times N}$, where $a_{ij}=e^{-\alpha |p_i-p_j|}$.

I am trying to find out the property of $\det(\mathbf{A}_\mathbf{p})$. Based some of my findings, I am confused by the following two subproblems:

$(\text{Q}1)$ Can we conveniently calculate the value of $\det(\mathbf{A}_\mathbf{p})=f(\mathbf{p})$ for a given $\mathbf{p}$? In other words, is there a way to explicitly unfold $\det(\mathbf{A}_\mathbf{p})$?

$(\text{Q}2)$ Is $\mathbf{A}_\mathbf{p}$ positive semi-definite?

$(\text{Q}3)$ Does $\det(\mathbf{A}_\mathbf{p})$ hit its minimal value only when $(p_{i+1}-p_i=1)$? By the way, in this case, $\mathbf{A}_\mathbf{p}$ will become a special symmetric Toeplitz matrix.

---

**A Toy Example:**

Given $N=3$, $D=10$ and $\alpha =1$. I construct $\mathbf{p}_1=[3,4,5]$ and $\mathbf{p}_2=[2,5,7]$. Then we have:

$$
\det \left( \mathbf{A}_{\mathbf{p}_1} \right) =\left| \begin{matrix}
 1&  e^{-1}&  e^{-2}\\
 e^{-1}&  1&  e^{-1}\\
 e^{-2}&  e^{-1}&  1\\
\end{matrix} \right|\approx 0.748,
$$

and

$$
\det \left( \mathbf{A}_{\mathbf{p}_2} \right) =\left| \begin{matrix}
 1&  e^{-3}&  e^{-5}\\
 e^{-3}&  1&  e^{-2}\\
 e^{-5}&  e^{-2}&  1\\
\end{matrix} \right|\approx 0.979 > \det \left( \mathbf{A}_{\mathbf{p}_1} \right) .
$$

---

**Some of My Efforts:**

I may have the following observations:

$(\text{O}1)$ The diagonal elements of $\mathbf{A}_\mathbf{p}$ are all ones since $|p_i-p_i|=0$.

$(\text{O}2)$ All elements of $\mathbf{A}_\mathbf{p}$ are in $[0,1]$.

$(\text{O}3)$ $\mathbf{A}_\mathbf{p}$ is symmetric since $|p_i-p_j|=|p_j-p_i|$.

$(\text{O}4)$ Actually, the order of $\mathbf{p}_i$s do not affect the value of $\det(\mathbf{A}_\mathbf{p})$.

I guess that $\mathbf{A}_\mathbf{p}$ has the following two properties:

$(\text{P}1)$ The answer of $(\text{Q}2)$ is "Yes", *i.e.*, $\mathbf{A}_\mathbf{p}$ is positive semi-definite.

$(\text{P}2)$ The answer of $(\text{Q}3)$ is "Yes", *i.e.*, $\left[\det(\mathbf{A}_\mathbf{p})=\min\left\{{\det(\mathbf{A}_{\mathbf{p}_k})}\right\}\right] \Leftrightarrow \left[ \forall i, ~p_{i+1}-p_{i}=1 \right]$.

The above conjectures of $(\text{P}1)$ and $(\text{P}2)$ is empirically presented. I write the following Python code to validate them and find that all randomly generated $\mathbf{A}_\mathbf{p}$ satisfy $(\text{P}1)$ and $(\text{P}2)$:

```
import numpy as np
import random
from scipy import spatial

alpha = 1
N = 10
X = np.arange(N).reshape(N, 1)
X = np.exp(-alpha * spatial.distance.cdist(X, X))
X_det = np.linalg.det(X)
for D in range(N, 1000):
    for i in range(100):
        p = np.array(random.sample(range(1, D + 1), N)).reshape(N, 1)
        A = np.exp(-alpha * spatial.distance.cdist(p, p))
        A_det = np.linalg.det(A)
        if A_det <= 0:
            print(A_det, p.reshape(N,))  # det(A) <= 0
            exit(0)
        if A_det < X_det and abs(A_det - X_det) > 1e-8:
            print(p, p.reshape(N,))  # det(A) < det(X) with numerical tolerance
            exit(0)
print('Done.')
```

I test many combinations of $\{\alpha, N, D\}$. I see that there is no any case satisfy the conditions of `A_det <= 0` and `A_det < X_det`.

---

**Why I Try to Study $\det(\mathbf{A}_\mathbf{p})$?**

I study the entropy of multivariate Gaussian distributions with some special covariance matrices (*i.e.*, the above defined $\mathbf{A}_\mathbf{p}$). The entropy value is related to $\det(\mathbf{A}_\mathbf{p})$ (you can see more details from my previous problems below).

I have made efforts and spent more than 14 days on it. Specifically, I read some textbooks, papers and blogs related to it. Here are some previous problems posted by me: [Problem 1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4524167/expectations-of-multivariate-gaussian-entropy), [Problem 2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4526630/prove-disprove-the-matrix-convergence-in-probability), [Problem 3](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4529767/prove-disprove-mathbbe-ln-det-mathbfa-rightarrow-0-when-bounded) and [Problem 4](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4525722/is-the-determinant-of-mathbfa-in0-1n-times-n-bounded). However, I am still stucked. Now I think that the key step is to resolve the problem I posted above.

I am sorry for occupying much public resource of this platform. But I really want to resolve the problems, especially $(\text{Q}2)$ and $(\text{Q}3)$. Could you please provide help or some tips?

Comment: Your matrix seems to have dominated main diagonal, hence one can estimate eigenvalues nicely by using Grishgorin circles. Then determinant could be estimated by product of eigenvalues. It may work.

Comment: Hi @Salcio, thanks for your attention! However, I may not know what is "Grishgorin circles". Could you please provide more details about that?

Comment: check out here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gershgorin_circle_theorem

Comment: This was cross posted on [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/430401).

Comment: Hi @prets, I was urgently finding the answer since I was confused by the problems for half a month. I first post the problem here, then I additionally posted it on MO. Sorry for occupying so much resource of these two platforms.

Comment: Hi @prets, I find that I can not delete this problem post since the bounty is not expired. What should I do?

Comment: The bounty attracted an answer from me. Now I see the OP is no longer interested. Is there a way to cancel the bounty and then delete the q? In fairness the OP should also be refunded if the q is deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q3 is actually relatively simple (and the beliw actually implies an answer to  Q1).

You have a matrix with the form

\begin{pmatrix}
1&m&mn\\m&1&n\\mn&n&1\\\end{pmatrix}

or something obtained from this by one row and one column interchange. The determinant is then

$1+m^2n^2-m^2-n^2=(1-m^2)(1-n^2)$

which is smallest when $m$ and $n$ are largest is absolute value. With your criteria for selecting entries $m=n=1/e$ is as large an absolute value as you can get for these parameters, hence the smallest possible determinant.

For the other two questions:

The form given above for the determinant can be used to cobstruct an answer to Q1. To wit, let the elements in your permutation be $k,k+d_1,k+d_1+d_2$ in ascending order. Then in the above you have $m=\exp(-d_1),n=\exp(-d_2)$ and thus the determinant will be

$(1-\exp(-2d_1))(1-\exp(-2d_2))$

which, as noted above, is minimal for $d_1=d_2=1$.

For Q3 note that for any positive whole numbers $k,l$, $|\exp(-k)+\exp(-l)|<1$. So the matrix is diagonally dominant with all positive elements in the diagonals. The guarantees *positive definite* matrix.

Comment: Hi @OscarLanzi, thanks for your help! I was trying to address the more general case of $N\times N$ matrix, where $N$ may be significantly larger than $3$. Actually, the original problem has been solved in https://mathoverflow.net/questions/430401/min-det-mathbfa-for-special-matrix-mathbfa.

Comment: Since I started a bounty which will be expired soon, and @OscarLanzi posts the only answer, here I would like to appreciate **OscarLanzi** for his/her kind help and accept the answer.